# C++ How to implement a compile time mapping from types to types?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, compile-time, type-mapping

Is there a canonical/reference implementation of a compile time map, which maps types to types?

For example, I would need a type mapping from `IBar -> IFoo` or from `int -> IFoo`.

At compile time I can then select `IFoo` when given a `IBar`.

How would one go about this with C++17?

Edit: here is an example using structs https://godbolt.org/z/EEvrYd9PE

Comment: Could you show how you want to use this?

Comment: Can you define it at one place or you need to add new types in many headers?

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot: one place is good enough. I know about compile time type lists, and need a compile time type map for type selection.

Comment: How do you need to access the map? Iterate through it? Using a the key and that's it?

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot: No iteration needed. Just simple key lookup.

Comment: Can you edit the question to add those requirement? That would make it clearer for future readers.

Comment: What do you mean by a "compile-time map". Is't template specialization sufficient, the way that type traits work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could define one with overloading and return types. This will act like a map data structure that you can  initialize and reuse with many types for many purposes.

```
template<typename T>
struct type_tag {
    using type = T;
};

template<typename K, typename V>
struct pair {
    using first_type = K;
    using second_type = V;
};

template<typename Pair>
struct element {
    static auto value(type_tag<typename Pair::first_type>) -> type_tag<typename Pair::second_type>;
};

template<typename... elems>
struct type_map : element<elems>... {
    using element<elems>::value...;

    template<typename K>
    using find = typename decltype(type_map::value(type_tag<K>{}))::type;
};
```

You can use it like this:

```
using my_map = type_map<
    pair<int, float>,
    pair<char, double>,
    pair<long, short>
>;

static_assert(std::is_same_v<my_map::find<int>, float>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<my_map::find<char>, double>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<my_map::find<long>, short>);
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/fT4qxKs4e)

It should be quite fast as the lookup is limited to the scope of the class only, and uses the compilers own overload resolution.

Comment: Great! This is what I was looking for.